# Anyone got evernote-mode with MACOSX and Port working with Emacs?

Tags: emacs, evernote

I've tried rvm(to install ruby 1.9.3.), and the ruby shipped with Macosx (Mountain lion), neither was drilled through.

Comment: I'm not sure what language this thread is in, but it looks like someone has got it working on OSX Lion:  http://blog.fumiz.me/2011/10/29/mac-os-x-lion%E3%81%A7emacs-evernote-mode%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86/

Comment: Seems to be Japanese, I'm looking into it. Thanks.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/emacs-evernote-mode/ This has been a little outdated, anyone knows if this packages still compatible with the current evernote? I was struggling with a newer version, whose repo is https://github.com/pymander/evernote-mode. After a whole day's effort, I ended up to ask help here.

Comment: Its using a (very) old version of the Evernote SDK (1.16) the current version is 1.25.  You may be able to swap in the new SDK: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ruby

Answer (score 1):

Evernote-mode has had it's share of issues of late (https://github.com/pymander/evernote-mode/issues). It used to work but stopped a few years ago.

Geeknote and Geeknote Mode do work quite well. https://github.com/avendael/emacs-geeknote